# Link to bounty questions is gone

Tags: support, bounty

On the listing of questions for a tag, there used to be a link to the bounty questions on the top, next to "newest", "active", "unanswered", etc.

Now it's gone. I don't remember whether or not I agreed to see Stack Overflow beta features, either way, I'm just curious why did this happen?

Comment: The _featured_ tab is visible to me. https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y4VbD.png. You are looking at the _new-nav_ design?

Comment: I dont know. If I am using the new nav. Assuming I am, why would the featured tab be removed

Answer (score 2):

The *featured tab**** has been renamed *bounties* in the new navigation design, and is visible at the right, it looks like a blue button:

[image]

*screenshot of what it used to look like, courtesy of [Aziz Shaikh](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/348095/link-to-bounty-questions-is-gone/348114#comment466681_348095):
[image]